# Transposing a column with SQL bigquery and getting values from other columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Currently, I have flattened a GA4 data set to individual rows. But now i am seeing that one record has the same date,event and timestamp:

what i have:

| date | event | key | int_value | str_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-01 | firstopen | system | 1 | null |
| 2022-04-01 | firstopen | engagementtime | 0 | null |
| 2022-04-01 | firstopen | device | null | android |
| 2022-04-02 | screenview | system | 0 | null |
| 2022-04-02 | screenview | engagementtime | 1 | null |
| 2022-04-02 | screenview | device | null | iphone |

what i'm trying to build:

| date | event | system | engagement_time | device |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-01 | firstopen | 1 | 0 | android |
| 2022-04-02 | screenview | 0 | 1 | iphone |

I would be doing this for all key and value fields that are nested. Is this the best way to turn it into an RDMS model?

I want to be able to create tables easier for analysts and users to query in cleaned transformed tables

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach would be:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH sample_table AS (
 -- put your table here.
)
-- query starts here
SELECT date, event,
       MAX(IF(key = 'system', int_value, NULL)) system,
       MAX(IF(key = 'engagementtime', int_value, NULL)) engagementtime,
       MAX(IF(key = 'device', str_value, NULL)) device,
  FROM sample_table
 GROUP BY 1, 2;

-- query result
+------------+------------+--------+----------------+---------+
|    date    |   event    | system | engagementtime | device  |
+------------+------------+--------+----------------+---------+
| 2022-04-01 | firstopen  |      1 |              0 | android |
| 2022-04-02 | screenview |      0 |              1 | iphone  |
+------------+------------+--------+----------------+---------+
```

And you can use `PIVOT` query as well.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  -- sample data
)
-- pivot query starts here
SELECT * FROM sample_table
 PIVOT (
   ANY_VALUE(COALESCE('' || int_value, str_value)) 
   FOR key IN ('system', 'engagementtime', 'device')
 );
```

- `'' || int_value` is same as `CAST(int_value AS STRING)`
- result is almost same as above but *system* and *engagementtime* column is a string type not an integer type in this case.